# Flickity is-selected issue

Tags: html, jquery, css, flickity

I'm trying to educate myself about Flickity. The carousel auto plays and the selected cell (denoted by the grey background) is automatically in the middle. I would like the selected cell not to be in the middle. I'm looking for a way to may it be the cell to the left, so it is above the dots (desktop view).

Hope that makes sense. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hutch011/okfu5wp3/1/) for it.
The only method that I can think of is using jQuery to find the prev sibling for the "is-selected" class and adding a class to it, but I was hoping there may be a simpler method

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

```html
<div class="carousel-outer-flick">
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell is-initial-select"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
<Slider
options {{
cellAlign: 'left' //this part will shift your entire slide to left
}}>

...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include an explanation of how this solves the problem.